# Search mysql databse with string parsed through URL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, url

I am parsing a url through the `rest API` to my `model` to retrieve data from my `mysql` database. Since the data is parsed as an `encoded url` mysql returns `zero results` for my search query as the url is parsed as,

`http://www.test.comindex.php/rest/resource/qstn/questionTitle/search%val`

and i think mysql tried to search the database with the value `search%val` without decoding the url.

Is there any work around for this matter. I've been struggling with this issue for quite some time now and im kinda new to this. :(

**Javascript parsing data**

```
     function doViewQ(qTitle) {

        var searchQ = document.getElementById("searchQVal").value;
        searchQ = encodeURIComponent(searchQ);
        qTitle = encodeURIComponent(qTitle);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/rest/resource/qstn/questionTitle/' + qTitle,

            success: function(data) {

                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);

                alert(jsonObj);

                document.getElementById('qres').innerHTML = '<tr><td><strong><a href="javascript:doViewQ()">'+ decodeURIComponent(jsonObj[0].questionTitle) + '</a></strong></br>'+ decodeURIComponent(jsonObj[0].questionBody) + '</td></tr>' ;


            },
            type: "get"     
        });
     }
```

**REST api controller**

```
    public function doGet()
    {
       // we assume the URL is constructed using name/value pairs
        $args = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(2);
        switch ($args['resource']) {
            case 'qstn' :
                $res = $this->student->getQ($args);
                if ($res === false) {
                    show_error('Unsupported request',404);
                }
                else {
                    // assume we get back an array of data - now echo it as JSON
                    echo json_encode($res);
                }
                break;                    

            default:
                show_error('Unsupported resource',404);
                break;
        }
    }
```

**MODEL retreving data from MySQL DB**

```
    public function getQ($args)
{
        // use array keys as column names for db lookup
        $where = array();
        $valid_column_names = urldecode(array('questionTitle'));

        // use only those $args vals (from URL) that match col names in students table
        foreach ($valid_column_names as $key) {
            if (isset($args[$key])) {
                $where[$key] = $args[$key];
            }
        }
        if (count($where) == 0) { // stop full select on table
            return false;
        }
        $this->db->where($where);
        $result = $this->db->get('questions');
        // return the results as an array - in which each selected row appears as an array
        return $result->result_array;

    }
```

Comment: I'm no PHP expert, but can you not use PHP's `rawurldecode()`?

Comment: try decoding the search values? $where[$key] = url_decode($args[$key]);

Comment: Mysql always searches the database for the string you pass to it. So there is no need to guess about that, if you pass a string, it will be searched by that string. So all you need to do, is to make the query you send to the database visible and look what is going on. Also compare with the data you have in the database and reproduce with Mysql client tools so that you can debug your query. The much code you have in your question only stands in your way btw. Do not post live-code here on SO, instead create an example from scratch with the bare minimum needed, e.g. 5 lines of code or so.

Comment: thank you guys for the responses :) i will post back after trying your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need PHP's `rawurldecode()`:

```
echo rawurldecode('foo%20bar%40baz'); // foo bar@baz
```

[PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)

Comment: thank you for the response :) i will post back after trying it out :)